# How can one call multiple executable files of Nauty?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

We know that Mathematica can call the "geng" function from [Nauty](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/). I have seen several examples of this on this forum. For example, (in windows),

```
geng = StartProcess[{"D:\\nauty_win\\geng.exe", "-C", "6"}]
While[(line = ReadLine[geng]) =!= EndOfFile, 
 Print@ImportString[line, "Graph6"]]
```

We are also aware that Nauty has many flexible options that can be combined.

For example, if we want to filter out all 10-vertex graphs with girth 6, we can execute the following command.

```
geng  10 -C |pickg -g6
```

The detailed information about the program is as follows (we get 6 graphs meeting requires):

```
I??FCpSJ?
I?AE@`gF?
I?BDA_ge?
I?`@?boBo
I?`@C`oB_
I?`D@bOBO
Z 9743542 graphs generated in 5.42 sec
Z 9743542 graphs read from stdin; 6 written to stdout; 3.35 sec
```

But how can Mathematica call these commands by combing these multiple executable files?

---

The reason I do this is that Mathematica and `nauty` have functions that can complement each other. For example, my goal is to **find two 2-connected graphs of order 12 with a girth of 6, and containing exactly two 8-cycles**

We can first use `nauty` to generate a file containing 2-connected bipartite graphs of order 12 with a girth of 6. Then, we can import the file and apply filtering. I believe there should be a more efficient approach by **combining these steps**.

```
 geng  14 -b -C |pickg -g6 >F.g6
 s = Import["F.g6", "GraphList"];
 Select[s, Length@FindCycle[#, {8}, All] == 2 &, 2]
```

Comment: 1) Wouldn't `RunProcess` be cleaner than `StartProcess`? 2) Store the output instead of calling `Print` (in practice there are very few reasons to use `Print`), and `RunProcess` will capture the output for you automatically 3) You can then pipe that output to a new `RunProcess` call

Comment: @b3m2a1 I know it should be possible to import all at once. The command below can do it. `IGImport["!D:\\nauty_win\\geng.exe 10 -C |D:\\nauty_win\\pickg.exe 
-g6", "Nauty"]` However, I haven't quite implemented what you mentioned.  I hope to import these graphs in an iterative manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`OpenRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) to create a stream:

```
stream = 
 OpenRead["!geng  10 -C | pickg -g6"]
```

When done, evaluate `Close[stream]`.

Comment: Hello, I've made an update to my question. My goal is to see if it's possible to achieve them (in one step) using Mathematica, instead of first generating graphs and saving them to files, and then importing and  using `Select` to filter them. Certainly, an iterative approach is preferable as it can save memory, especially when dealing with a large number of graphs.

Comment: @licheng The approach I suggested here does not involve files. Everything is done through pipes. What this means is that you don't need to wait for nauty to finish generating graphs before you can start reading them with Mathematica.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? After using your command, I don't know what to do next. Thank you advance.

Comment: @licheng You can do the same as in your post, `While[(line = ReadLine[stream]) =!= EndOfFile,  Print@ImportString[line, "Graph6"]]`